# c# Find out variating column in html table

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

How can I find out the sixth column in this html table (using for example HTML Agility Pack or Regex)?

```
<tr><td>So, 22.05.16</td><td>1</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>190</td><td>DifferentThings</td></tr>
```

In the last column could stand anything and this is only one row of many, so I want the full last column with every entry.

---

Edit:

If there is an blank

```
<td></td>
```

in the 6th row I always get an

```
System.NullReferenceException
```

What shoud I do now?

```
innerTextOfLastCell = lastTdCell.InnerText.Trim();
```

is causing the error

---

Edit:

Solved it!

Just typed:

```
if (lastTdCell != null) //Not lastTdCell.InnerText.Trim()!
{
    innerTextOfLastCell = lastTdCell.InnerText.Trim();
    s = s + innerTextOfLastCell + "\n";
    run.Text = s;
}


else
{
    s = s + "\n\n";
    run.Text = s;
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474659/how-to-get-the-value-from-a-specific-cell-c-sharp-html-agility-pack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `HtmlAgilityPack`, this should work regardless of the number of columns the table has.

```
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml("<table><tr><td>So, 22.05.16</td><td>1</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>190</td><td>DifferentThings</td></tr></table>");
var root = html.DocumentNode;
var tableNodes = root.Descendants("table");
var innerTextOfLastCell = string.Empty;
foreach (var tbs in tableNodes.Select((tbNodes, i) => new { tbNodes = tbNodes, i = i }))
{
    var trs = tbs.tbNodes.Descendants("tr");
    foreach (var tr in trs.Select((trNodes, j) => new { trNodes = trNodes, j = j }))
    {
        var tds = tr.trNodes.Descendants("td");
        var lastTdCell = tds.LastOrDefault();
        innerTextOfLastCell = lastTdCell.InnerText.Trim();
    }
}
```

**[edit]**


If you did want to use the other option from [How to get the value from a specific cell C# Html-Agility-Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474659/how-to-get-the-value-from-a-specific-cell-c-sharp-html-agility-pack), then you could try the following code:

```
HtmlNode lastTdnode = root.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]/tr[last()]/td[last()]");
```

This will give you the **last** `<td>` from the **last** `<tr>` from the **first** `<table>`


If you wanted the sixth cell you can use something like this, but will give you the same result as above:

```
HtmlNode sixthTdNode = root.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]/tr[last()]/td[6]");
```

If you wanted to mix it up even more you can try this:

```
HtmlNode nthTdNode = root.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]/tr[last()]/td[" + 6 + "]");
```

Comment: I get an error message each time I try to run it with more than one table. (See edit in question).

Comment: Thats odd, the code is meant to be dynamic regardless of the number of tables and or columns. If you haven't already fixed the issue, you can post the code you used and I can check it out.

Comment: Ok thanks :). Sry for asking this, but what is root in this case?

Comment: In this case root is the <table> node, if you were to pull from a website it would most likely be <html>. Its meant to be the root node (first node) or the document element

Comment: Ok Thanks :). I used for Example .ElementAtorDefault(0); to get the cells I want. Thanks again for your time and skill :D.